# Верстка сложного блока

Tags: html, css, svg

Стоит задача сверстать данный блок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять как сверстать фигуру с clip-path

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.info {
  width: 680px;
}

.info__inner {
  height: 100%;
}

.info__advantages {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 25px;
}

.info__advantage {
  padding: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 0.56px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 22px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.info__advantage:not(.info__advantage--rhombus) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(98deg, #4BA6DD 16.55%, #D96BC1 42.44%, #F90 81.89%);
}

.info__advantage--rhombus {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 217px;
  height: 217px;
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  margin: auto;
}

.info__advantage--rhombus::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: inherit;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  background-image: linear-gradient(98deg, #4BA6DD 16.55%, #D96BC1 42.44%, #F90 81.89%);
}

.info__advantage--onion {
  padding: 175px 30px 30px 30px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 55% 50%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 70% 100%, 30% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.info__advantage:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  width: 256px;
  height: 140px;
}

.info__advantage:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  margin: auto;
}

.info__advantage:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 13;
}

.info__advantage:nth-child(4) {
  width: 165px;
  height: 165px;
}

.info__advantage:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column-start: 6;
  grid-column-end: 13;
  width: 161px;
  height: 170px;
}

.info__advantage:nth-child(6) {
  grid-row-start: 3;
  width: 184px;
  height: 213px;
}

.info__advantage:nth-child(7) {
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-column-start: 3;
}

.info__advantage:nth-child(8) {
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-column-start: 5;
  grid-column-end: 13;
  width: 184px;
  height: 178px;
}

.info__advantage--br-20 {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.info__advantage--br-140 {
  border-radius: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="info__inner">
    <ul class="info__advantages">
      <li class="info__advantage info__advantage--br-20">профессиональное комьюнити</li>
      <li class="info__advantage info__advantage--br-20 info__advantage--rhombus">дипломная работа — собственный мультфильм</li>
      <li class="info__advantage info__advantage--br-140">только в России свыше 12 000 заказов ежедневно</li>
      <li class="info__advantage info__advantage--br-140">портфолио к выпуску</li>
      <li class="info__advantage info__advantage--br-20">растущая индустрия с оборотом 150 млрд</li>
      <li class="info__advantage info__advantage--br-140">стажировки и практики с 1 курса</li>
      <li class="info__advantage info__advantage--br-20 info__advantage--onion">преподаватели-практики</li>
      <li class="info__advantage info__advantage--br-140">уникальная творческая профессия</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Проблема в вёрстке блока "преподаватели-практики"?

Comment: @darinkapoznyak да

Comment: https://codepen.io/darinka-poznyak/pen/ZEVVZOR

Comment: но, если нужно именно через li, а не через div, то сброшу через li

Comment: Мне нужно сделать углы закругленными как на макете

Comment: А у Вас ограничения по способу создания этого блока есть? Т.е. Вам можно его создавать только при помощи clip-path и ничего другого использовать нельзя?

Comment: @darinkapoznyak без ограничений

Comment: Тогда проще будет Вам воспользоваться svg. Есть много библиотек. Найдите тот же самый svg bookmark (вариаций много), а потом уже разукрашивайте его и позиционируйте так, как Вам надо

Comment: @darinkapoznyak Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @Alexandr_Yakovlev Добавил метку `svg` так как есть ответ полностью на svg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добиться такого скругления, как Вы хотите, при помощи clip-path довольно сложно. Если у Вас нет ограничений по способу создания такого блока, то рекомендую Вам рассмотреть не clip-path, а svg. Вот Вам несколько вариантов для примера:

```html
<svg width="256px" height="256px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0" transform="rotate(180)">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="myGradient" gradientTransform="rotate(98)">
      <stop offset="16.55%" stop-color="#4BA6DD" />
      <stop offset="42.44%" stop-color="#D96BC1" />
      <stop offset="81.89%" stop-color="#F90" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g><g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></g><g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier"> <path d="M4 9C4 6.17157 4 4.75736 4.87868 3.87868C5.75736 3 7.17157 3 10 3H14C16.8284 3 18.2426 3 19.1213 3.87868C20 4.75736 20 6.17157 20 9V15.8276C20 18.5109 20 19.8525 19.1557 20.2629C18.3114 20.6733 17.2565 19.8444 15.1465 18.1866L14.4713 17.656C13.2849 16.7239 12.6917 16.2578 12 16.2578C11.3083 16.2578 10.7151 16.7239 9.52871 17.656L8.85346 18.1866C6.74355 19.8444 5.68859 20.6733 4.84429 20.2629C4 19.8525 4 18.5109 4 15.8276V9Z" stroke="#222222" fill="url('#myGradient')"></path></g></svg>
```

```html
<svg width="256px" height="256px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(180)">
  <defs>
  <linearGradient id="myGradient" gradientTransform="rotate(98)">
      <stop offset="16.55%" stop-color="#4BA6DD" />
      <stop offset="42.44%" stop-color="#D96BC1" />
      <stop offset="81.89%" stop-color="#F90" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g><g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></g><g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier"> <title>Bookmark</title> <g id="Page-1" stroke-width="0.072" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"> <g id="Bookmark"> <rect id="Rectangle" fill-rule="nonzero" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24"> </rect> <path d="M17,4 L7,4 C5.89543,4 5,4.89543 5,6 L5,18.7929 C5,19.2383 5.53857,19.4614 5.85355,19.1464 L11.6464,13.3536 C11.8417,13.1583 12.1583,13.1583 12.3536,13.3536 L18.1464,19.1464 C18.4614,19.4614 19,19.2383 19,18.7929 L19,6 C19,4.89543 18.1046,4 17,4 Z" id="Path" stroke="#0C0310" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url('#myGradient')"> </path> </g> </g> </g></svg>
```

```html
<svg width="256px" height="256px" viewBox="0 0 24.00 24.00" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0" transform="rotate(180)">
  <defs>
  <linearGradient id="myGradient" gradientTransform="rotate(98)">
      <stop offset="16.55%" stop-color="#4BA6DD" />
      <stop offset="42.44%" stop-color="#D96BC1" />
      <stop offset="81.89%" stop-color="#F90" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g><g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></g><g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier"> <path d="M21 11.0975V16.0909C21 19.1875 21 20.7358 20.2659 21.4123C19.9158 21.735 19.4739 21.9377 19.0031 21.9915C18.016 22.1045 16.8633 21.0849 14.5578 19.0458C13.5388 18.1445 13.0292 17.6938 12.4397 17.5751C12.1494 17.5166 11.8506 17.5166 11.5603 17.5751C10.9708 17.6938 10.4612 18.1445 9.44216 19.0458C7.13673 21.0849 5.98402 22.1045 4.99692 21.9915C4.52615 21.9377 4.08421 21.735 3.73411 21.4123C3 20.7358 3 19.1875 3 16.0909V11.0975C3 6.80891 3 4.6646 4.31802 3.3323C5.63604 2 7.75736 2 12 2C16.2426 2 18.364 2 19.682 3.3323C21 4.6646 21 6.80891 21 11.0975Z" fill="url('#myGradient')"></path></g></svg>
```